# Does fast travelling affect the blood moon?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

I got a quest that can only be completed during a blood moon. I kept that in mind and went on with my business until the next blood moon occured. I got the blood moon cutscene and then, because I was too far away, teleported to a shrine near the quest objective. As I arrived, though, I could not complete the quest. As it seemed, the blood moon disappeared when I fast travelled.

What happened? Usually, fast travel does not change the time of day, so did I travel for 24 ingame hours or what? Are there other things that are changed when I fast travel?

By the way, the quest I am talking about is

> the "Under a red moon" shrine quest where you have to stand without equipment on a shrine plate. When I arrived at the plate, I think it was supposed to glow orange (that's what should happen when it is active). Instead, it did not glow with any color.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Blood moons disappear as soon as midnight hits and the cutscene activates. You must do that quest *before* the cutscene, while the moon itself is bright red in the sky.

After the blood moon cutscene occurs, you can watch the moon quickly fade back to its smaller, white form, which will not let you finish that shrine quest.

During the daytime, there is an NPC at Duelling Peaks Stable that will tell you if there will be a blood moon that night or not.

Comment: Thanks! I always thought the blood moon would stay until 5 am when morning breaks. I'll edit my question..

Comment: I happened to catch sight of the blood moon rising early in an evening. I travelled to a shrine near the quest in question and hightailed it there. I made it in time. This quest will activate the platform throughout the evening until the cutscene is played.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is when you see you are in a Blood Moon night, time travel backwards (restore a recent save) to a point where you have time to get to that shrine.